# Number limiting in a Textview

Tags: android, textview

I have problem in my android app:
I write a multiply code like 2223 * 3.456 that it will 7682.688 , my problem is that i don't want that text view display this 7682.688 but I want to display 7682.6.
I know about android:maxlength but when I use this it doesn't display my comment like "foot" beside of it , My question is that how can i limit the calculating of this?
My Textview in xml is:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/foot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLength="8"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

and my multiply code in Activity is:

```
    TextView point = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.foot);
    if(ft1.getText().toString().length() == 0 ){return;}
    int first = Integer.parseInt(ft1.getText().toString());
    double equal = first *3.456;    
    String x = equal+" foot";
    foot.setText(x);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `DecimalFormat` to only display the number of decimals you want.

example

```
DecimalFormat formatDecimal = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
foot.setText(formatDecimal.format(YourCalculationResult));
```

Comment: it was so help full   but what can i write instead of (YourCalculationResult)); please don't forget that it is like a calculator

Comment: Your calculation is your total variable total = a+ b.

Comment: Hi again , I have another question:                                           how can I hid the zero in result in TextView for example my code is DecimalFormat formatDecimal = new DecimalFormat("#000.00");  then it show 2*4 = 008.00 then when a larger number entered show this field , Thank you

Comment: @Vahid u can check by this `if (String.parseString(x).contains(".")){ // contains decimal }`